# Replace em angularJs

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

> `<br><br>`Essa criação poderosa - forjada à imagem de uma gárgula - o
>    manteve`<br><br>` seguro em suas jornadas, permitindo que ele
>    desempenhasse seu importante trabalho sem medo de retaliações daqueles
>    hostis à sua terra natal.`<br><br>` Isso é, até despertar a ira do
>    Alto Comando Noxiano com suas sentinelas.`<br><br>`

Usando `{{content.lore}}` no meu html exibo o texto acima. Quando tento usar `content.lore.replace("<br>", "")` as palavras `<br>` não são substituidas. Como posso fazer para substituí-las?

Comment: Poste um trecho do código javascript que você possui, se possível.

Comment: Achei a solução no SO, coloco aqui ou apago a pergunta?

Comment: Responda sua própria pergunta, ela pode ser a dúvida de outros usuários (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das maneiras é usando um filtro que converte o HTML para texto:

```
app.filter('htmlToText', function(){
  return function(html){        
     return angular.element('<div>').append(html || '').text();
  };
});
```

Na view:

```
{{content.lore | htmlToText}}
```